# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Юзаю 3.6.5 версию python'a
Собстна вот код

```
def decorator(function_to_decorate):
    def wrapper():
        print('Код который выполняется до функции')
        function_to_decorate()
        print('Код который выполняется после функции')
        return wrapper

def function_which_want_to_be_wrapped():
    print('Хочу быть обёрнутой')

function_which_want_to_be_wrapped()
function_which_want_to_be_wrapped = decorator(function_which_want_to_be_wrapped)
function_which_want_to_be_wrapped()
```

Выбрасывает ошибку 
    line 12, in 
        function_which_want_to_be_wrapped()
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не оттуда возвращаете результат, в декорирующей функции.

```
def decorator(function_to_decorate):
    def wrapper():
        print('Код который выполняется до функции')
        function_to_decorate()
        print('Код который выполняется после функции')
    return wrapper
```